# Adding Java ME platform in netbeans 8.0

Tags: java, netbeans

I am having trouble installing the ME platform for Netbeans 8.0 - I have:

- Installed Netbeans IDE 8.0
- Installed jmesdk-3.4
- Installed the jmesdk-3.4 plugin & activated it in Netbeans

When I try to create a New Java ME > Mobile application project
I get a warning saying

> No Java ME Platform found. Please add at least one

When i try to add the java platform by locating the jmesdk-3.4  folder, it tells me no platform was detected automatically(failed) and it requires me to add manually.But adding it manually just creates more confusion.
need help please.

Answer (score 9):

**How to install JAVA ME SDK 3.4**

- Go to the Java ME SDK Download page [javame-sdk/downloads/index.html](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/javame/javame-sdk/downloads/index.html).

[image]

---

- Click the Accept License Agreement option.
- Create an Account or login
- Download the Java ME SDK installer file and save it to any location on your computer.
- Double-click the installer file to run the installer, and follow the instructions.
- Remember the installations directory. e.g. -> U:\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.4

When the installation is complete,

the Java (TM) ME Platform SDK Device Manager icon appears in the Windows system tray.

[image]

- Unzip the downloaded `oracle-jmesdk-3-4-rr-nb-plugins.zip` to a folder
  e.g. `oracle-jmesdk-3-4-rr-nb-plugins`

[image]

**How to activate Java ME support in NetBeans IDE?**

- Choose Tools > Plugins from the main IDE's toolbar.
- In the Plugins dialog box, click the Installed tab and select Java ME in the list of available features.
- Click Activate.
- At the Welcome panel of the Installer dialog box, click Activate.
- When the activation is successfully completed, click Finish.
- Click Close to close the Plugins dialog box.

[image]

**How to register Java ME SDK as a platform in NetBeans IDE?**

- Choose Tools > Java Platforms in the IDE.
- In the Java Platform Manager dialog box, click Add Platforms.
- In the Add Java Platform dialog box, select Java ME CLDC Platform Emulator and click Next.
- Select the folder where Java ME SDK is installed in the Choose directory to search for platforms dialog box and click Open.
- Ensure the Java ME SDK platform is chosen in the Add Java Platform dialog box and click Next.
- After the IDE detects the platform, click Finish. Java ME SDK should now be registered in the IDE.
- In the Java Platform Manager dialog box, click Close.

[image]
[image]
[image]

**How to install the downloaded plugin**

- Go to Tools -- Plugins -- Downloaded
- Click Add Plugins
- Navigate to the Plugin folder e.g. `oracle-jmesdk-3-4-rr-nb-plugins`

[image]

- Select all .nbm

[image]

- Restart Netbeans

[image]

enjoy the new program examples

[image]
[image]

Done

[More Information wiki.netbeans](http://wiki.netbeans.org/JavaMESDKSupport)

Comment: Thanks moskito-x for your time. However i used the same steps you have described above but the j2me platform is not automatically detected when i try to add the platform. it then give an option of registering the platform as a Custom Java Me platform. But i dont know the procedures of doing this. Thanks

Comment: @user2468097 : remove `Java ME` from `Plugins -> installed` prob. Get you a `this will also remove ...` ?  and remove it . Then follow the steps one by one. I also got first a red line telling me `there ist no Jave ME found install it manually.` I was not able to install it manually. Got always the same message. I deinstall all and have it done as described above. and it works.

Comment: Tried this with Netbeans 8.1 as described above. After IDE restart there is no new project category "Samples/Java ME SDK 3.4". Creating a new Java ME project is also not possible. There is the message "No Java ME platform found" although there is the java me sdk 3.4 in the Java Platform Manager.

Comment: @ChristianSchäfer : The best if not working . uninstall all related to ME SDK. Clean up folders with ME SDK stuff . Start ME SDK install from scratch. Sorry I have to install it also twice.

Comment: On select platform type step I'm getting "there is no platform selected for installation".
If I select Custom Java ME CLDC then netbeans freezes.
Netbeans version: 8.1 / 8.2
Java_ME_platform_SDK: 8.3

Comment: @wishmaster35 : Sorry but I have no information about SDK: 8.3 . I will look at next free time.

Comment: This problem is due to last version of java.

https://community.oracle.com/thread/4009110

Comment: @moskito-x Thanks Successfully worked in netbeans 8.2 with jdk 1.8

Comment: @ThilinaMD :-) Glad it worked after 4 years now.  That's not always the case.

Answer (score 1):

I did what the other answer recommends, which worked, but only when using Netbeans IDE 7.4 and JDK 1.7 for a 32-bit system (https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html). Currently using a Windows 10 64-bit system. Note that I did not accept any updates for the required Java ME plugins, as I hear that might make things crash.

Answer (score 1):

I heve readed that that can be being caused by the new serialization filter feature in the JDK([Serialization Filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/core/serialization-filtering1.htm#JSCOR-GUID-3ECB288D-E5BD-4412-892F-E9BB11D4C98A). Seems that it was added to JDK 8 after the 112 update so on this update of the JDK it shall work but it certainly is possibly to use the Java ME SDK on JDKs with this feature. I did it at least on JDK 1.8.0_192. To this I had to make some changes on the java.security file.
The chages were:

- Remove the # on front of jdk.serialFilter
- Replace the texto after
  jdk.serialFilter to *
- Romove the # on front of
  sun.rmi.registry.registryFilter property and of it parametres and
  remove the whitespaces and / from the same.
- Do the same on the
  sun.rmi.transport.dgcFilter property.
- Append ;* at the last parameter
  of sun.rmi.registry.registryFilter

It seems to be importante to not corrupt the parameters because I do this and the emulator wasn't starting.

I tried on JDK 11.0.1 and it don't work.

Comment: Please note, without evidence/proof this is not really a good answer, more of a comment. You can try improving your answer by looking up relevant content online (issue management system tickets, release notes, etc..), and adding excerpts and links to your answer. In the meanwhile, have a look at [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)