# Missing emulators when trying to create a Java ME app in Netbeans

Tags: java, android, windows, netbeans

I've followed a myriad of outdated tutorials and walk-throughs for installing the Java ME SDK and related NetBeans plugins into the latest Netbeans 8.0.1 on Windows 7 Pro.

All seems to be ok, everything activated and in it's place, but when creating a new Mobile project and I get to the following screen (see below) to choose with emulator to use, the fields are blank.  I shrug, click 'next', and of course now the project complains about 'missing resources'.

Has any one experienced this before? Will try under Linux and Mac OS X later, just in case it's an OS-related flub.

[image]

Comment: you can try this answer : [Adding Java ME](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24347772/1322642). Hope it helps.

Comment: I have tried that one, but thanks for the link.  Will apply it to a Linux install later today and hope for a more promising result.